# Decide convergence divergence of $\sum \dfrac{1}{(\ln n)^{\ln n}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

Does the series $\sum \dfrac{1}{(\ln n)^{\ln n}}$ converges?

I can intuitively say that it converges, because $(\ln n)^{\ln n} $ is going to $\infty$ on a hayabusa

Comment: For the records, going to $\infty$ is not enough. $n$ goes to $\infty$ but $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges. You have to compare with $\frac{1}{n^\alpha}$ ($\alpha >1$) to prove what you want, which was the answers below do.

Comment: What is a hayabusa?

Answer (score 13):

For $n$ large enough, $\ln n>9>e^2$. Then 
$$\frac{1}{(\ln n)^{\ln n}}\le \frac {1}{e^{2\ln n}}=\frac{1}{n^2}.$$
The series is convergent.

Answer (score 5):

$(\ln n)^{\ln n} = e^{\ln n \ln \ln n} = (e^{\ln n})^{ \ln \ln n}=n^{\ln\ln n} > n^2$ when $n$ is large enough

Answer (score 0):

$(\ln n)^{\ln n}$ is equal to $n^{\ln\ln n}$. (In general $x^{\ln y}=y^{\ln x}$.)

So for large enough $n$, the denominator is larger than $n^{1+\epsilon}$, which is enough for convergence by the $p$-series test.